# UITableView still slow with blocks

Tags: objective-c

so i have a tableView in my app, which basically run the names and images of some user's friends from Facebook.
The problem is that when i drag the tableView up and down, it's slow and not smooth like it should be, although i use block to upload images from Facebook- so it's asynchrony. 
Now, after i implement a block for upload images from Facebook, it is run faster then it was before the block- but still not smooth enough.

is anybody know how to deal with it?
here is some of my code:

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"friendCell"];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                          reuseIdentifier:@"friendCell"];
      [friendsTableView reloadData];
   }

   //set data for user's friends images
   NSURL *url;
   NSString *stringID;
   stringID = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=square",facebookFriendsID[indexPath.row] ];
   url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringID];

   //Calling block function to hendle user's friends images from facebook
   [self downloadImageWithURL:url :stringID :cell completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
       if (succeeded) {
          cell.imageView.image = image;
       }
   }];

   //For friends name...
   cell.textLabel.text = facebookFriendsName[indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:17.0f];
   [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
   cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;

   return cell;

}
```

And the downloadImage block:

```
//For upload the images from Facebook asynchrony- using block.
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url : (NSString *)string : (UITableViewCell *)cell completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if ( !error )
                           {
                               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

                               completionBlock(YES,image);

                           } else{
                               completionBlock(NO,nil);
                           }
                       }];
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code has 4 problems, all of which are contributing to the slowness:

1. Delete `[friendsTableView reloadData];` - you should never reload the table from inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. You should not reference `cell` from inside your completion block:

   ```
   [self downloadImageWithURL:url :stringID :cell completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
       if (succeeded) {
           cell.imageView.image = image;
       }
   }];
   ```

   By the time your image downloads, `cell` may have been reused and be displaying different content.  This can cause the wrong avatar image to appear.  Instead, use `indexPath` to get the current cell by calling `UITableViewCell *currentCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` and set the image on that.
3. You are creating a new network request every time a cell appears.  If the user scrolls very fast, you will have lots of simultaneous network requests.  You may want to start network requests in `scrollViewDidScroll:` instead, when the scroll view slows down.
4. You are not de-duplicating network requests.  If a user scrolls up and down really fast, they will generate lots of network requests to the same URL.  You need to cache already-downloaded images and use those if the network request has already been made.*

The SDWebImage library has already solved all of these problems; you may simply want to use it instead of reinventing the wheel.  At the very least, it's worth reading their code: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

---

* - NSURLCache may be caching the images for you, depending on the server's `cache-control` headers.  But even so, this cache is slow (it caches the NSData representation, not the UIImage representation), and NSURLConnection will not stop you from starting 4 identical requests simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Also, pay attention, that you load your image data for second time from main thread in request completion block:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

you need to use **NSData *data** parameter from completionHandler - `^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**BUT**, as Aaron Brager noted, you don't need *reinventing the wheel* instead of using ready solution, like SDWebImage. so, all it matter if only you going to clarify how it works